# Find with php specific parameters in XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing, extract

Hello i have the follow problem.

I have e XML file and i know the value of "uniquename=value2". I want extract the value of URL.

```
<set uniquename="value1">
  <items>
    <item>
      <units>
         ...
      </units>
    </item>
    <item>
      <units>
        ...
        <url>http://www.something</url>
        ...
      </units>
    </item>
  </items>
 </set>
 <set uniquename="value2">
  <items>
    <item>
      <units>
         ...
      </units>
    </item>
    <item>
      <units>
        ...
        <url>http://www.something2</url>
        ...
      </units>
    </item>
  </items>
 </set>
```

Someone has suggestions?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply with [simplexml](http://php.net/simplexml) and [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-xpath.php):

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$nodes = $x->xpath('set[@uniquename="value2"]/items/item/units/url');

$url = (string)$nodes[0];
```

Comment: +1, simple and clean answer.  I had started to respond with an answer about simplexml, and then realized I hadn't done a lot of work with it and I wasn't sure what the object structure would be like, or how to access it.  That's what I love about SO... you always learn something.

Comment: Oops, nitpick point.  The poster's xml is in a file, so you'd probably want to use `simplexml_load_file()` instead.